# How to gracefully handle child package error in parent package?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

We have a SSIS project where the parent package uses five "Execute Child Package" to call multiple child packages in parallel. For most of our packages, we want everything to function as default (ie. if child package fails, master package fails). However, for a small number of our packages, we want the parent package not to stop if those child packages fail so that it can continue through the rest of the ETL pipeline.

Unfortunately, the Propagate property has no effect in a parent-child relationship. A "propagate to parent package" boolean property is exactly what would work. I found both of these MS Connect items which relate to my issue. 
([Connect 1](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/486780/ssis-propagate-property-has-no-effect-on-parent-packages),
[Connect 2](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/486780/ssis-propagate-property-has-no-effect-on-parent-packages))

I found some solutions online using ForceExecutionResult and MaximumErrorCount. However, those solutions work for all child packages but my solution is conditional by package (only n child packages should have this behavior, not all). I'm trying to find a workaround to the lack of "Propagate to parent package".

SSIS 2012

Comment: Are you allowed to make changes to the child packages to accomplish this?

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, although it would be painful with over 250 packages. But that's definitely an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevention of error Propagation from Child to Parent Package-SSIS Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793279/prevention-of-error-propagation-from-child-to-parent-package-ssis-workaround).